# how do i get index of listview item where its subitem equal some string without using selected items?

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-xe7

i currently use list view inside my project i wanted to get index of some item by finding its subitem string , i have listview with item and subitem , `item caption := name` and `subitem := id` i want to find the index  of this item where `sub item  := id` , how could i do that , i searched while for some equations and didn't got one yet . reason that i need this  because the subitem id have unique id and this much secure instead of using find item by caption

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to loop through the list view's `Items`, looking at the proper subitem that you want to match. For instance, given a `TListView` with three columns (A, B, and C), to search through column B to find something:

```
function TForm1.FindListIndex(const TextToMatch: string): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
    if ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[1] = TextToMatch then
      Exit(i);
  Result := -1;
end;
```

Of course, substitute your own matching function (SameText, for instance):

```
if SameText(ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[1], TextToMatch) then
   ...;
```

If you want to search for a match in *any* sub-item, you just need a nested loop:

```
function TForm1.FindListIndex(const TextToMatch: string): Integer;
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
    for j := 0 to ListView1.Items[i].SubItems.Count - 1 do
      if ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[j] = TextToMatch then
        Exit(i);
  Result := -1;
end;
```