# Deleting,Changing Listview in real time

Tags: delphi, listview

I'm facing a problem changing subitems  rows On a listview ...

```
 with form1.ListView1.Items.Add do
    begin
    Caption :=  var1;
    SubItems.Add(filename);
    SubItems.Add(var2);
    SubItems.Add(timetostr(time));
    SubItems.Add(var3);
end;
```

That's  the listview items it will be added in real time [it can be from 1 to 20 rows]

lets say "var2"   will be updated with downloading status (speed) but if finished deleted the row ...(That's oke i have no problem with that )

the problem is when i delete one row, items index of listview will be changed (If 9 got deleted  10 will be the 9 ..) in this way how i can update the right item with the right value !

i hope you understand my problem !

Comment: 1) Store the original index in the `TListItem.Data` property (using `Data := Pointer(Index);`), and search for the proper index for `var2` when you need to update it. 2) At runtime, search for the item you need to update, and then update it once you find it. I just recently posted code to [search a listview for a subitem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30249688/62576).

Comment: Or have just a collection of the objects that you'll update, and use that list view as a viewer (in virtual mode).

Comment: I agree with TLama. Use `TListView` in virtual mode, storing your actual data in your own list somewhere else, and use the `TListView.OnData` event to display the data (use the `TListItem.Data` to cross-reference into your data list).  When you need to make an update, update your data directly, and then trigger a redraw of the `TListView.TListView` using `TListView.Invalidate()` or `TListView.UpdateItems()` for a specific index.  When you add/remove items to your data list, update `TListView.Items.Count` accordingly, and let `OnData` grab the new data as needed.

Comment: Life is always easier once you stop using your gui control as a data structure. Virtual mode ftw.